# Python - changing element value of a list in list

Tags: python

I have a list in list. All the values are False. I have to change value to True of a very specific one.

```
s=[[False,False,False,False]
   [False,False,False,False]
   [False,False,False,False]
   [False,False,False,False]]
```

I want to change it into this:

```
s=[[False,False,False,False]
   [False,False,False,False]
   [False,True,False,False]
   [False,False,False,False]]
```

P.s.:
I tried doing this:

```
s[2][1]=True
```

But i got this:

```
[[False,True,False,False]
[False,True,False,False]
[False,True,False,False]
[False,True,False,False]]
```

Comment: `s[i][j] = True`? If you know the indexes

Comment: how did you create the list in the first place

Comment: What you've posted is a `TypeError`, your assignment to `s` isn't valid therefore cannot reflect your actual data.

Comment: How have you created the `s`?

Answer (score 0):

Add commas in order to *build* your matrix.

```
s=[[False,False,False,False],
   [False,False,False,False],
   [False,False,False,False],
   [False,False,False,False]]

s[2][1]=True

for i in s:
    print i
```

Outputs:

```
[False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False]
[False, True, False, False]
[False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: 1. It's *"com**m**as"*. 2. The OP's code won't actually run, without the commas you get a `TypeError`, not an issue with references.